# Is lein-heroku 0.1.1 compatible with leiningen 2?

Tags: heroku, clojure, leiningen

I'm having some trouble with lein-heroku 0.1.1 and lein 2.

I have a fresh install of lein from https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Upgrading on OS X Lion.

Here are the vitals:

```
$ lein --version
Leiningen 2.0.0-preview10 on Java 1.7.0_09 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

$ cat ~/.lein/profiles.clj 
{:user {:plugins [ 
    [lein-heroku "0.1.1"]
    [lein-difftest "2.0.0"]
    [lein-pprint "1.1.1"]
]}}

$ lein help
...
leiningen.heroku  Problem loading: Could not locate leiningen/main__init.class or leiningen/main.clj on classpath:
...
```

The other plugins load successfully.

Here's the classpath:

```
$ lein repl
user=> (println (seq (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader))))
(#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.0.0-preview10-standalone.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/org/clojure/core.cache/0.6.1/core.cache-0.6.1.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/quoin/quoin/0.1.0/quoin-0.1.0.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/lein-heroku/lein-heroku/0.1.1/lein-heroku-0.1.1.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/stencil/stencil/0.3.0/stencil-0.3.0.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/lein-pprint/lein-pprint/1.1.1/lein-pprint-1.1.1.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.2/httpclient-4.1.2.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/slingshot/slingshot/0.8.0/slingshot-0.8.0.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.2/httpcore-4.1.2.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/org/clojars/technomancy/heroku-http-apache/0.1-SNAPSHOT/heroku-http-apache-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/scout/scout/0.1.0/scout-0.1.0.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.3.0/clojure-1.3.0.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/lein-difftest/lein-difftest/2.0.0/lein-difftest-2.0.0.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/org/clojure/tools.cli/0.2.1/tools.cli-0.2.1.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/bultitude/bultitude/0.1.7/bultitude-0.1.7.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/1.7.1/gson-1.7.1.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/org/clojars/technomancy/heroku-json-gson/0.1-SNAPSHOT/heroku-json-gson-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/lein-newnew/lein-newnew/0.3.5/lein-newnew-0.3.5.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/org/clojars/technomancy/heroku-api/0.1-SNAPSHOT/heroku-api-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar> 
#<URL file:/Users/bnorton/.m2/repository/doric/doric/0.6.0/doric-0.6.0.jar>)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to grab the latest version of lein-heroku from master.

The commit log shows some changes to support Leiningen 2, but those are newer than the last release.

See commits: https://github.com/technomancy/lein-heroku/commits/master

Comment: Thanks, I needed a second pair of eyes. A `lein install` from master and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

It has been updated for 2.x, but it's not being maintained any more. Due to startup time issues and unnecessary duplication of effort I recommend using the Heroku Toolbelt instead. http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com

Comment: The "Getting Started with Clojure on Heroku" [Devcenter article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure) mentions [lein-template](https://github.com/technomancy/lein-heroku/tree/master/lein-template), which is really what I wanted out of the lein-heroku plugin. `lein new heroku myapp` was quite a handy way to get started, but there may be an easier way to make the template available.